# Как вызвать хранимую процедуру с массивами в параметрах?

Tags: массивы, postgresql, процедуры

```
    --типы в виде массивов, все в схеме "my_shema"
CREATE TYPE my_shema.t_date_tab AS (
  t_date_tab TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE []
);

CREATE TYPE my_shema.t_number_tab AS (
  t_number_tab BIGINT []
);

CREATE TYPE my_shema.t_string_tab AS (
  t_string_tab VARCHAR(50) []
);    

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_shema.insert_new_tracks (
  p_original_id my_shema.t_number_tab,
  p_vehicle_id my_shema.t_number_tab,
  p_datetime0 my_shema.t_date_tab,
  p_lat0 my_shema.t_number_tab,
  p_lon0 my_shema.t_number_tab,
  p_datetime1 my_shema.t_date_tab,
  p_lat1 my_shema.t_number_tab,
  p_lon1 my_shema.t_number_tab,
  p_distance my_shema.t_number_tab,
  p_original_road_id my_shema.t_number_tab
)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
BEGIN
        FOR i in P_ORIGINAL_ID.first .. P_ORIGINAL_ID.last
        LOOP
           BEGIN
             INSERT into MY_TABLE(ORIGINAL_ID, VEHICLE_ID, DATETIME0, LAT0, LON0, DATETIME1,
                                        LAT1, LON1, DISTANCE, ORIGINAL_ROAD_ID)
             VALUES (P_ORIGINAL_ID(i), P_VEHICLE_ID(i), P_DATETIME0(i), P_LAT0(i), P_LON0(i), P_DATETIME1(i),
                     P_LAT1(i), P_LON1(i), P_DISTANCE(i), P_ORIGINAL_ROAD_ID(i));
             COMMIT;

            EXCEPTION
            when others then
                rollback;
                raise;
          END;
        END LOOP;
END;
$body$
```

--Вот так не получается:

```
select * from my_shema."insert_new_tracks"(ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[],
                                              ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[],
                                              ARRAY['2001-01-01','2001-01-01']::TIMESTAMP[],
                                              ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[],
                                              ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[],
                                              ARRAY['2001-01-01','2001-01-01']::TIMESTAMP[],
                                              ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[],
                                              ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[],
                                              ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[],
                                              ARRAY[1,2]::bigint[]);
```

Вывод postgeSQL:

> ERROR:  function my_shema.insert_new_tracks(bigint[],
>   bigint[], timestamp without time zone[], bigint[], bigint[], timestamp
>   without time zone[], bigint[], bigint[], bigint[], bigint[]) does not
>   exist LINE 1: select * from
>   my_shema.insert_new_tracks(ARRAY[1,2]...
>                         ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так композитный тип и не должен подходить для массивов во входных параметрах. Это совсем разные типы данных. В одном композитном типе может быть представлено много разных данных, возможно в том числе иметь массив из элементов композитного типа.

Композитный тип в виде литерала возможно указать [через синтаксис `row`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html)

```
row(array[1,2]::int[])
```

В таком случае уже возможно определить соответствие параметров функции:

```
create type my_type as (rg int[]);
create function test_my_type(i_val my_type) 
  returns setof int 
  language plpgsql as $$ 
    begin 
      return query select unnest(i_val.rg);
    end;
  $$;

select test_my_type(row(array[1,2]::int[]));

select test_my_type(row(array[1,2]::int[])::my_type); --либо даже добавить явное приведение типов
```

Возможно, вы искали не композитные типы, а [домены](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html):

```
create domain my_type as int[];
create function test_my_type(i_val my_type) 
  returns setof int 
  language plpgsql as $$ 
    begin 
      return query select unnest(i_val);
    end;
  $$;

select test_my_type(array[1,2]::int[]);
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Ваш ответ мне помог.

Comment: А еще не подскажете @Мелкий, как организовать цикл внутри процедуры по композитному типу. Пытаюсь так но ругается, что можно только по массивам:    
    
`BEGIN
    DECLARE
 i  BIGINT :=1; --счетчик цикла (необходим)
        ii BIGINT; --переменная цикла
  BEGIN
        FOREACH ii IN ARRAY P_ORIGINAL_ID --"P_ORIGINAL_ID -это композитный тип,cмотри выше"
          LOOP....END LOOP;`

Comment: P_ORIGINAL_ID.t_number_tab видимо. В композитном типе может быть много разных полей. Чем кстати было бы и неплохо вам воспользоваться, судя по коду: то есть сделать композитный тип из вставляемых данных построчно и передавать в хранимку массив композитных типов. Ну и использовать `insert .. on conflict` вместо старинного и сильно медленного перехватывания исключений из неявных savepoints.

Comment: спасибо за помощь @Мелкий. Еще вопрос про эти типы - как к ним обратится по индексу (есть цикл, внутри цикла запрос, i - это счетчик): `update my_table SET my_flag = 1 where ID = (P_ID).t_number_tab[i]`. Прочитал, что в запросах можно их обрамлять в скобки, но postgres пишет ошибку: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: ...$8::BIGINT]).t_number_tab and CONNECTION_STATUS=0 FROM (SELE...
'

Comment: сообщение об ошибке явно от другого запроса. Синтаксис `(P_ID).t_number_tab[i]` вполне корректен, даже локально проверил.